# Can't load current product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, helper, magento2.3.4

I try to load the current product in gallery.phtml

**Helper** (app\code\Company\Base\Helper\Data.php):

```
...

use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data as CatalogHelper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    ...

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_product;

    protected $_catalogHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ProcessorFactory $layoutProcessorFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        \Magento\Cms\Block\Block $cmsblock,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $interface,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $address,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        CatalogHelper $catalogHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

    ) {
        $this->_layoutProcessorFactory = $layoutProcessorFactory;
        $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->_blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->cmsblock = $cmsblock;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_object = $interface;
        $this->_currencyCode = $currencyFactory->create();
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_address = $address;
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_dir = $dir;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;

        $this->_store = $storeManager->getStore();
        $this->_catalogHelper = $catalogHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_product)) {
            $this->_product = $this->_catalogHelper->getProduct();
        }

        // DEBUG
        var_dump($this->_product->getData()); exit();    // Output: array(0) { }


        return $this->_product;
    }

    public function getProductName()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getName();
    }

    ...

}
```

**Layout** (THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\override\base\catalog_product_view.xml):

```
<container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery"
           name="product.info.media.image"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
            <argument name="imageHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image</argument>

            <argument name="product_name" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Base\Helper\Data::getProductName" />
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

**gallery.phtml** (THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml):

```
$productName = $block->getProductName();
exit("'".$productName."'");
```

---

**Output:**

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: where do I miss echo?

Comment: hi @black try this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310679/cant-load-current-product/310821#310821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing lines from the constructor

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ProcessorFactory $layoutProcessorFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
    \Magento\Cms\Block\Block $cmsblock,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory, 
    // \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,                <--- not needed anymore
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $interface,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address $address,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    CatalogHelper $catalogHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

) {
    $this->_layoutProcessorFactory = $layoutProcessorFactory;
    $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->_blockRepository = $blockRepository;
    $this->cmsblock = $cmsblock;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    // $this->_product = $product;            <--- I had to remove this
    $this->_httpContext = $httpContext;
    $this->_object = $interface;
    $this->_currencyCode = $currencyFactory->create();
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    $this->_address = $address;
    $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;

    $this->_store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $this->_catalogHelper = $catalogHelper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **try this code**

```
protected $registry;

public function __construct(
    ......................................
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ......................................
) {
    ......................................
    $this->registry = $registry;
    ......................................
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
}
```

> **And in you phtml file**

```
$product_data = $block->getCurrentProduct(); // here this is all data of current product 

$product_entityid = $product_data->getEntityId(); // get product id

$product_sku = $product_data->getSku(); // get sku

$product_name = $product_data->getName(); // get name 

exit("'".$product_name."'");
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***